# window.onmousewheel in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mousewheel

This code disabled mouse scroll functionality, when i click on the document.

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
    window.onmousewheel = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but, this working in all browsers except Firefox. tell please, how to make this code as cross-browser ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support `.onmousewheel`, you have to use the [`DOMMouseScroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#DOMMouseScroll) event instead:

```
$(document).on( "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: for those using versions of 1.7 or less of jQuery I would recommend using .bind or .one instead of on as on is only supported in 1.7 and beyond

Answer (score 6):

Firefox does not support the `onmousewheel` name for this event. You'll need to do it with the `DOMMouseScroll` event instead.

To detect whether `onmousewheel` is supported, you can do something like this:

```
var cancelscroll = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};

if ("onmousewheel" in document) {
    document.onmousewheel = cancelscroll;
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', cancelscroll, false);
}
```

Note that you needn't do this on DOM ready: the document will always be available to bind to, so you can do it immediately.

---

You ask how to remove the event listener in each case.  A similar conditional will do the trick:

```
if ("onmousewheel" in document) {
    document.onmousewheel = function() {};
} else {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', cancelscroll, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the (new) standardised event `wheel`. Docs:

- [W3C standard: DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-wheelevents)
- [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel)
- [Quirksmode compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html) (doesn't list cutting-edge versions)

I've found this works in Firefox v29.0.1 and Chrome v35.0.1916.114 on OSX (10.9.3), but not in Safari v7.0.4.

Comment: Best up-to-date answer with helpful links!